# Get details of ungrouped columns in comma separated values in Sql-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, window-functions, having-clause

I want to get employee leaves whose lvdays sum is greater than 30 with all three table details . Not able to find a way out for this .

employee :

```
empcode| MNGR_CODE| MNGR_CODE2
-------|----------|-----------
AA     |   bb     |     cc 
FF     |   bb     |     cc
```

lvtype :

```
typeid| desc
------|---------
1     | casual
```

leave :

```
leaveid| empcode| lvdays| typeid| Flag| date      | reason 
-------|--------|-------|-------|-----|-----------|---------
1      |  AA    | 2     |    1  |  1  | 11-02-2020| NULL 
2      |  AA    | 3     |    1  |  1  | 02-11-2019| NULL
3      |  FF    | 4     |    1  |  1  | 23-12-2019| NULL
```

Here is the query i am trying to build but not able to achieve the goal .

```
SELECT MNGR_CODE,
       MNGR_CODE2,
       lt.desc,
       l.reason,
       l.leaveID
FROM Leave l
     INNER JOIN lvtype lt ON l.typeid = lt.typeid
     LEFT OUTER HASH JOIN employee em ON em.Emp_Code = l.empcode
WHERE empcode IN ('AA', 'FF')
  AND leaveID IN (SELECT leaveID
                  FROM Leave l
                       INNER JOIN lvtype lt ON l.typeid = lt.typeid
                  WHERE l.empcode IN ('AA', 'FF')
                  GROUP BY l.empcode
                  HAVING SUM(lvdays) > 30);
```

Comment: FYI `DESC` is a reserved keyword in SQL Server. Reserved words are best avoided when creating objects, and if you do have them you *must* quote them. Without doing so, your code will error. In this case, the above would actually generate the error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'desc'.`

Comment: On a different note, why the `HASH` in `LEFT OUTER HASH JOIN employee em`? And why a `LEFT JOIN` when you cause it to be an implicit `INNER JOIN` in the `WHERE`? `empcode IN ('AA', 'FF')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* I followed you correctly, you could use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        e.mngr_code,
        e.mngr_code2,
        lt.desc, 
        l.reason,
        l.leaveid,
        sum(l.lvdays) over(partition by e.empcode) sum_lvdays
    from leave l 
    inner join lvtype lt on l.typeid = lt.typeid 
    inner join employee em on em.emp_code = l.empcode
) t
where sum_lvdays > 30
```

The subquery is based on your existing query, and adds an additional column that does a window sum of all leaves of each employee. The outer query uses the results of the window sum as a filter.

I am unsure that you do need a `left join` in the subquery, so I changed it to an `inner join`.